# HTML Select field is not selecting the first value by default

Tags: html, select, bootstrap-4, dropdown, html5-history

I am using the angular js and HTML to create some basic website and I have a drop-down menu with 3 options for some reason the first value in the option field is not selected by default. The HTML page on the browser shows the blank option (even though I do not have the blank option in my select list);

HTML on the browser:

[image: HTML on the browser]

HTML code:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="eventtype2" ng-model="formAdata.eventtype2" class="form-control">
        <option class="dropdown-item" value="ordinaryevent">Ordinary Event</option>
        <option class="dropdown-item" value="errordeclaration"> Error Declaration </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

My requirement is that the first option `Ordinary Event` should be selected in the field on the load of the page. I tried the option `selected` but still no luck. On the load of the page for a fraction of second the field shows the value `Ordinary Event` but then it vanishes. I am not trying to hide it in angular or something not sure why.

I have also tried following but no luck:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<select id="eventtype2" ng-model="formAdata.eventtype2" class="form-control">
    <option class="dropdown-item" value="ordinaryevent" selected>Ordinary Event</option>
    <option class="dropdown-item" value="errordeclaration"> Error Declaration </option>
</select>
```

I tried adding the following command to my angular:

```
$scope.formAdata.eventtype2 = 'ordinaryevent';
```

But after adding this command for some reason my other dropdowns which are being populated from node.js is getting messed up:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 form-group">
    <label for="eventtype1" class="col-md-3 control-label">Event Type</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select id="eventtype1" ng-model="formAdata.eventtype1" class="form-control" ng-options='eventtype1 for eventtype1 in eventType'>
            <option class="dropdown-item" value="" disabled selected>Select Event Type</option>
            <option class="dropdown-item" value="{{eventtype1}}"> {{ eventtype1 }} </option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select id="eventtype2" ng-model="formAdata.eventtype2" class="form-control">
            <option class="dropdown-item" value="ordinaryevent" selected>Ordinary Event</option>
            <option class="dropdown-item" value="errordeclaration"> Error Declaration </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
    app.controller('AppController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.formAdata.eventtype2 = 'ordinaryevent';

    $scope.createEvents =   function(){
        $http({
            url: "/createEvents",
            method: "POST",
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            data: $.param($scope.formAdata)
        }).success(function(response) {
            $scope.xmldata  =   response[0].XML;
            $scope.jsondata =   JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(response[1].JSON), undefined, 4);
        }).error(function(error) {
            console.log(error)
        });
    }

    $scope.init = function () {
        $http({
            url: "/populateFields",
            method: "GET"
        }).success(function(response) {
            $scope.businessSteps    =   response.businessStep;
            $scope.eventType        =   response.eventType; 
        }).error(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    };
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could set the default value of `formAdata.eventtype2` model in the controller to be your desired default value

e.g.

you can have this in your controller

```
$scope.formAdata.eventtype2 = 'ordinaryevent';
```

or whatever value you have on the first option

---

For the second problem try this

```
<div class="col-md-4" ng-if="eventType">
    <select id="eventtype1" ng-model="formAdata.eventtype1" class="form-control" ng-options='eventtype1 for eventtype1 in eventType'>
        <option class="dropdown-item" value="" disabled selected>Select Event Type</option>
        <option class="dropdown-item" value="{{eventtype1}}"> {{ eventtype1 }} </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

```
app.controller('AppController', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.formAdata = {
    eventtype1: '',
    eventtype2: 'ordinaryevent',
};

$scope.createEvents =   function(){
    $http({
        url: "/createEvents",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        data: $.param($scope.formAdata)
    }).success(function(response) {
        $scope.xmldata  =   response[0].XML;
        $scope.jsondata =   JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(response[1].JSON), undefined, 4);
    }).error(function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    });
}

$scope.init = function () {
    $http({
        url: "/populateFields",
        method: "GET"
    }).success(function(response) {
        $scope.businessSteps    =   response.businessStep;
        $scope.eventType        =   response.eventType; 
    }).error(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
};

$scope.init();
```

Comment: Thanks the this works fine:
$scope.formAdata.eventtype2 = 'ordinaryevent';

Comment: But this is impacting my other dropdown which is being populated using the angularjs and list I am obtaining from nodejs model. Previously other dropdown was populated with values properly but after adding this command none of the dropdown fields are populated it just shows the `{{ variable name }}`

Comment: not sure what you mean to be honest, can you elaborate more? what's working before and how its broken?

Comment: Basically I have 2 dropdown with eventtype1 and eventtype2. eventtype2 is being populated directly in the HTML with option but eventtype1 list is pretty huge so I have stored the options in the nodejs model and I am calling the nodejs function in the angular to populate it. Before adding the command you provided eventtype1 was working fine but eventtype2 was not selecting the first value but after adding your command eventtype2 is working fine but eventtype1 for some reason is messed up and not being populatred now. I will add the code to my main question.

Comment: I'm still not sure where `eventtype1` came from since its not in your snippet anywhere.
But I suspect you just need to change `$scope.formAdata.eventtype2 = 'ordinaryevent';` to `$scope.formAdata = {eventtype1: '', eventtype2: 'ordinaryevent'}` probably

Comment: I have posted the complete code in my main question. Please have a look at it. Initially I was only bother about eventtype2 so I did not mention about eventtype1 but after modification of eventtype2 as it is messing eventtype1 I included that as well. I tried the code `$scope.formAdata = {eventtype1: '', eventtype2: 'ordinaryevent'}` and it does not seem to solve the issue related to eventtpye1 although it solves the eventtpye2 issue.

Comment: Okay, so I'm not sure why your code works in the first place since that additional line shouldn't affect the `$scope.eventType` at all. In my understanding `$scope.init` is never trigerred, so what you need to do is add `$scope.init()` after your `$scope.init` has been declared. If that still doesn't work, you might need to hide the dom until the request has been completed i.e. add `ng-if="eventType` in `<select id="eventtype1"...`

Comment: You are right, If I add `$scope.formAdata.eventtype2 = 'ordinaryevent';` then the `$scope.init()` the function is not getting called. I did not understand the solution you mentioned `add $scope.init() after your $scope.init has been declared` do you mean to add the command `$scope.init();` after the completion of function, if so then I tried that and no luck. It seems so simple but not sure why I have gotten stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the "selected" in the default options

```
<option value="xx" selected>...
```

Comment: I have tried this and it does not seem to work for me. Although on the initial load the options are shown it would disappear immediately I am not sure why and how the options are disappearing. If I click on the field then I can see the option but I am hopeing the first option should be seleted by default.

Answer (score 0):

Use Selected attribute

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="eventtype2" ng-model="formAdata.eventtype2" class="form-control">
        <option class="dropdown-item" selected value="ordinaryevent">Ordinary Event</option>
        <option class="dropdown-item" value="errordeclaration"> Error Declaration </option>
    </select>
</div>
```